# Bootstrap modal isn't getting prop value on the popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following codes in two files.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modals from "./Modals";

const Names = (props) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  let na = props.name;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setEdit(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="horizontal-card mb-3">
      <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
        <div className="horizontal-profile">
          <div className="horizontal-title">{props.name}</div>
          <div className="forms"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="forms">
          <Modals name_us={props} key={props.id} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Names;
```

I've passed the prop from the above components and trying to use its value in the Modals component below.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Modals = ({ name_us }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mb-4">
        <div className="col text-center" key={name_us.name}>
          <button
            className="btn btn-sm btn-success"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#basicModal"
          >
            {name_us.name}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          className="modal fade"
          id="basicModal"
          tabIndex={-1}
          role="dialog"
          aria-labelledby="basicModal"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                  {name_us.name}
                </h4>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                {/* <input type="hidden" name="categorys" value={name_us.name} /> */}
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="update_category" value={name_us.name} />
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-default"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                  saves
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Modals;
```

Now in the modal body, I'm trying to set the input value as a name from the prop I get in the component but it is always showing the name of the first element in every element. How do I fix it? It's working fine on the button name for each component which is being clicked to show the modal popup.

Comment: Show code where you use Names component